# check XPath in VTD-XML is evaluating to XML Tag (or) Text (or) List of Tag (or) list of Text

Tags: java, xml, xpath, vtd-xml

Consider the below XML sample Structure as an input.
I am using VTD-XML:2.11 for parsing the XML using Java-8. The scenarios is like I need to parse the below XML depending on the provided XPath and return a List that contains the values evaluated by the XPath. At any point the XML that needs to be parsed and the XPath are not fixed each time my parse will have new XML as an input with new XPath.

```
Ex1: XPath: //CATALOG/CD/TITLE/text()
 output: - Empire Burlesque
         - Still got the blues
         - Hide your heart

Ex2: XPath: //CATALOG/CD/TITLE
 output: - <TITLE id="1">Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
         - <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
         - <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
```

One of main problem that I am facing is I am not able to check if the evaluated XPath is a XML Element or XML text?.

Note: I do not want to check if the given XPath is ending with "`text()`" to know if the XPath evaluation will be a text or Element.

```
<CATALOG>
 <CD>
    <TITLE id="1">Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
    <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Gary More</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Virgin redords</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
 </CD>
 <CD>
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
 </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Please let me know if any one would like me to add extra information in order to fully understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VTD-XML's VTDNav object allows you to check the identity of a token by using its getTokenType() method call.... Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes. I guess this might solve my problem. but "vNav.getTokenType(vNav.getCurrentIndex())" is returning an "int" value. returning "5" if I am pointing to "../text()" in xpath. and returning "0" if I am pointing to an xml Element "../TITLE". Is there a list of constants to  which I can point out to these integer values. like "VTDNav.NC/NS/P/R..etc"

Comment: but think about all the axis to which you navigate the cursor, are there first child(FC), last child(LC), next sibling (ns), prev sibling (ps), and parent (P)...

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got the meaning of `text()` and `xml element` wrong. the simple text you get in your first example is still XML.., although it is missing any tags.

I don't know, if this is relevant for you, but just imagine a nested structure like here:

```
<CATALOG>
 <CD>
    <TITLE id="1">Empire Burlesque<SubNode>Some Value here</SubNode>Some more Text</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
 </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

The XPath without `text()` will return everything inside. You'd even need `text()[1]` or `text()[2]` to get the two existing text parts.

If you can be sure, that there is no deeper nesting, You might handle the result of your code as xml and query it again using an XPath of `'(//text())[1]'`. This should deliver the naked text in both cases.

### Hint

If the XML is under your control you might consider an XML like here:

```
<CATALOG>
    <CD Titel="Some title" Artist="Some artist" ... more attriubtes ... />
</CATALOG>
```

### A working example (but not in your tool)

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YourXml XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(N'<CATALOG>
 <CD>
    <TITLE id="1">Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
 </CD></CATALOG>')
 ,(N'<CATALOG><CD>
    <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
 </CD></CATALOG>')
 ,(N'<CATALOG><CD>
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
 </CD>
</CATALOG>');

SELECT YourXml.query('(/CATALOG/CD/TITLE/text())[1]')
      ,YourXml.query('(/CATALOG/CD/TITLE/text())[1]').value('(//text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
      ,YourXml.query('(/CATALOG/CD/TITLE)[1]')
      ,YourXml.query('(/CATALOG/CD/TITLE)[1]').value('(//text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @tbl;
```

The result

[image]

This is `T-SQL` but you can see, that I call `.query()` twice, once with `text()` and again without. One returns the naked text (but still as XML), one returns the text within `<TITLE>` tags. The `.value()` with an `XPath` of `'(//text())[1]'` will return the first `text()` wherever it is found.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. As I mentioned in my Question I do not have any control in the XML. I may receive any kind of XML with any XML structure. My question is in regards with the VTD-XML java library functions to check if the evaluated XPath is having any text/tag or not. Mean while I got your point about "text() is also XML". I will see if my code works for both in the same manner or not.But any additional suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: @GhostRider See my update, hope this helps... At least it should point the direction

Comment: really thanks for your update. But what I am looking for is really specific to the Java Code and I can not use any other tool/Language(  Like T-Sql which you have specified). I am able to achieve this using the normal XSLT which will not suite to my requirement. I am giving you an upvote and leaving my question as un answered so that others can give answer specific to java VTD-XML library. Thank you once again